# Rules for implicit int return type in ANSI C function declarations

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c89

I know that `f(void) { return 0; }` has an return type of `int`, even though it isn't specified, but what about the following:

```
(*f())[]{}

(*g())(){}

const*h(){}
```

This compiled with no errors on gcc with `-ansi -Werror -pedantic` and only complained about the missing return statement in clang: https://godbolt.org/z/jAYL4v

`f` seems to have a return type of `int(*)[]`, `g` seems to have a return type of `int(*)()`, and `h` seems to have a return type of `const int*`.

In the ANSI C standard, I can't seem to find the rule for this. I checked [6.5.4.3 Function declarators (including prototypes)] and [6.7.1 Function definitions], but couldn't even find anything on the implicit int return type (except in some example code). Am I just looking in the wrong place? Is this valid code?

Comment: Are you really asking about the 1989 ANSI C standard? Are you working with 30-year-old code or writing new code for a system using a 30-year-old compiler? Or did you make a mistake in selecting which version of the standard you wanted to ask about?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I was writing for code golf (least bytes to make a program do something) and I found it strange that I could write `int*h(){}` as `*h(){}` and couldn't find out why (and to my knowledge C89 was the only standard that had default int return types where this question could make sense)

Comment: as Eric stated it is pointless to discuss a prehistoric standard. many programmers  were not even born when it become obsolete

Comment: @P__J__: I stated no such thing, and it is not true. There is old code in service today, and some people need to work with it.

Comment: lol @ these comments. "this is not relevant to me so it is pointless"

Comment: @mm 1. he is not working with the old code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The grammar for Function Definitions (C89 3.7.1) is:

> *function-definition:*
>      *declaration-specifiers<sub>opt</sub> declarator declaration-list<sub>opt</sub> compound-statement*

which is the same as C99 except that the *declaration-specifiers* are optional in C89.

The meanings of those grammar terms are:

- *declaration-specifiers* is any combination of *storage-class-specifier*, *type-specifier*, and *type-qualifier*; examples of which are  `static`, `float`, `const` respectively.
- *declarator*, informally, is anything that could appear here: `int ______ ;` . There is a formal definition of it of course but I mention this approach so you can relate the terminology to your existing understanding of declaration syntax.
- *declaration-list* refers to K&R-style parameter declarations.
- *compound-statement* is a braced list of statements (possibly empty).

In your question, the following are declarators:  `(*f())[]`  `(*g())()` `*h()` . So it is legal to have them followed by `{}` (which is *compound-statement*).  The `h` also has a *declaration-specifier*.

In C89 there's also a rule (3.5.2) that providing no *type-specifier* in a set of *declaration-specifiers* is equivalent to providing `int`. C99 added a constraint "At least one type specifier shall be given in the declaration specifiers in each declaration [...]".

Comment: Or 6.7.1 and 6.5.2 in C90, which is what the OP appears to be looking at. And noting `gcc -ansi` still means `-std=c90` even though gcc's _default_ has finally been updated to `gnu11`.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 OK. As it happens I have a copy of a C89 draft but not a copy of C90